# AJAX/Javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, function

Hi I am using an ajax call to a function called build_Array.  This function should break up myString which is "Call 1-877-968-7762 to initiate your leave.,1,0,through;You are eligible to receive 50% pay.,1,365,through;Your leave will be unpaid.,1,0,After;" 
into sections divided by the commas into a 2d array.  But it is not working.  It says all of the values for the array are undefined.  Here is where I call the function inside the ajax...  (It works in the jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/ChaZz/3/)

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      var myString = request.responseText;
      myString = build_Array(myString);
      document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = myString;
    }
  }
```

And here is the function build_Array...

```
function build_Array (myString) {
  var mySplitResult = myString.split(';');
  var myArray = new Array(mySplitResult.length);

  //may need to get rid of -1
  for(var i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length -1; i++){
    myArray[i] = new Array(4);
    var mySplitResult2 = mySplitResult[i].split(',');

    for(var z = 0; z < mySplitResult2.length; z++) {
        myArray[i][z] = mySplitResult2[z];
    }
  }
  var final_message = myArray[1][1];
  return final_message;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/ChaZz/5/

```
var myString = "Call 1-877-968-7762 to initiate your leave.,-30,0,through;You are eligible to receive 50% pay.,0,365,through;Your leave will be unpaid.,365,0,After;";

function build_Array (myString) {
  var mySplitResult = myString.split(';');
  var myArray = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
    myArray[i] = [];
    var mySplitResult2 = mySplitResult[i].split(',');

    for(var z = 0; z < mySplitResult2.length; z++) {
        myArray[i][z] = mySplitResult2[z];
    }
  }
  var final_message = myArray[1][1];
  return final_message;
}

console.log(build_Array(myString)); // 0
```

Comment: what does the console.log do?

Comment: The developer console that is in every modern browser.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the loop to copy from mySplitArray2 to myArray, just assign the array returned by `split` directly to that element of the new array. And `array.push` can be used to build up an array incrementally.

```
function build_Array (myString) {
  var myArray = [];
  for (substring in myString.split(';')){
    myArray.push(substring.split(','));
  }
  var final_message = myArray[1][1];
  return final_message;
}
```